# Python code syntax operation with random and time libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3.6+vscode to compile a program, but it shows an error, but I continue to debug, no improvement.

Hope to get some help！

**Below is the code:**

```
from random import random
from time import perf_counter
DARTS = 1000*1000
hits = 0.0
start = perf_counter
for i in range(1,DARTS+1):
    x, y = random(), random()
    dist = pow(x ** 2 + y ** 2, 0.5)
    if dist <= 1.0:
        hits = hits + 1
pi = 4 * (hits/DARTS)
print("圆周率值是：{}".format(pi))
print("运行时间是：{:.5f}s".format(perf_counter()-start))
```

Comment: Please also post the error.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Did you mean: start = perf_counter()  ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, your 5th line should look like this:

- `start = perf_counter()`

In your last line you're subtracting a function from a number:

- `print("运行时间是：{:.5f}s".format(perf_counter()-start))`

**Correct code**

```
from random import random
from time import perf_counter
DARTS = 1000*1000
hits = 0.0
start = perf_counter()
for i in range(1,DARTS+1):
    x, y = random(), random()
    dist = pow(x ** 2 + y ** 2, 0.5)
    if dist <= 1.0:
        hits = hits + 1
pi = 4 * (hits/DARTS)
print("圆周率值是：{}".format(pi))
print("运行时间是：{:.5f}s".format(perf_counter()-start))
```

**What you were trying:**

`print("运行时间是：{:.5f}s".format(perf_counter()-perf_counter))`